# Extract first table of Outlook mail folder

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to extract first table of each mail of a specific folder to Excel. If there is more than one table in the mail we can exclude it and move to next mail item.  Below is the code I have at the moment. Could you please help?

```
Public Sub Import_Tables_From_Outlook_Emails()
    Dim oApp As Outlook.Application, oMapi As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem, HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim tables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection, table As MSHTML.HTMLTable
    Dim objExcelApp As Excel.Application, x As Long, y As Long, destCell As Range
    Dim objExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook, objExcelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'Create a new excel workbook
    Set objExcelWorkbook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Add
    objExcelApp.Visible = True
    Set destCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oApp = GetObject(, "OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")
    If oApp Is Nothing Then Set oApp = CreateObject("OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set oMapi = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder
    If Not oMapi Is Nothing Then
        For Each oMail In oMapi.items
             'Get HTML tables from email object
              Set HTMLdoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument 
            With HTMLdoc
                .Body.innerHTML = oMail.HTMLBody
                Set tables = .getElementsByTagName("table")
            End With
            For Each table In tables
                For x = 0 To table.Rows.Length - 1
                    For y = 0 To table.Rows(x).Cells.Length - 1
                        destCell.Offset(x, y).Value = _
                            table.Rows(x).Cells(y).innerText
                    Next y
                Next x
                Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
                Range("A1").Activate
                Set destCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
            Next
        Next
    End If
    Set oApp = Nothing
    Set oMapi = Nothing
    Set oMail = Nothing
    Set HTMLdoc = Nothing
    Set tables = Nothing
    MsgBox "Finished"
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you running the code from within Excel or Outlook?

Comment: I'm running it from outlook.

Answer (score 1):

The following macro prompts the user to select a folder from Outlook, loops though each item in the folder, and copies the first table from each item to a separate worksheet in a newly created workbook.

***Edit***
The code has been edited to 1) restrict the mail items based on ReceivedTime, 2) sort the restricted items by ReceivedTime, and in descending order, 3) loop through the items from earliest to latest date.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Import_Tables_From_Outlook_Emails()

    Dim oMapiFolder As Folder
    Dim oMail As Object
    Dim oMailItems As Object
    Dim oRestrictItems As Object
    Dim oHTMLDoc As Object
    Dim oHTMLTable As Object
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWkb As Object
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set oMapiFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder
    If oMapiFolder Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        xlApp.Visible = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set xlWkb = xlApp.workbooks.Add(-4167) 'xlWBATWorksheet

    Set oHTMLDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")

    Set oMailItems = oMapiFolder.Items

    Set oRestrictItems = oMailItems.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" & Format("1/1/17 12:00am", "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'")

    oRestrictItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", olDescending

    For i = 1 To oRestrictItems.Count
        Set oMail = oRestrictItems(i)
        With oHTMLDoc
            .Body.innerHTML = oMail.HTMLBody
            Set oHTMLTable = .getElementsByTagName("table")(0)
        End With
        If Not oHTMLTable Is Nothing Then
            xlWkb.Worksheets.Add after:=xlWkb.activesheet
            For r = 0 To oHTMLTable.Rows.Length - 1
                For c = 0 To oHTMLTable.Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1
                    xlWkb.activesheet.Range("A1").Offset(r, c).Value = _
                        oHTMLTable.Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
                Next c
            Next r
            Set oHTMLTable = Nothing
        End If
    Next i

    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlWkb.Worksheets(1).Delete
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True

    Application.ActiveExplorer.Activate

    Set oMapiFolder = Nothing
    Set oMail = Nothing
    Set oHTMLDoc = Nothing
    Set oHTMLTable = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlWkb = Nothing

    MsgBox "Finished"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks aton. It helps.

Comment: Hi, I have a query regarding the Vba line "For Each oMail In oMapiFolder.Items" where vba is looping through each mail item, Is it follows any specific patter? I did the sorting of mail by received date but still not getting table in sequence. Loop is first taking data of mailitem of  15-Aug'18 then 1-Sep'18 and then 31-Aug'18. I want to understand how does this looping work or how can I extract the data based on mail received date.

Comment: You can use the Restrict method of the Items object described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict).

Comment: Thanks. I have added below line :  oMapiFolder.items.Restrict "[ReceivedTime] > '" & Format("1/1/18 0:01am", "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'" but issue is not yet resolved. I moved all other items from the folder and left with two items. One of it came on 31st Aug'18 and other on 1st sep'18. When for loop is running for each item it is first extracting the details of 1st Sep'18 and then moving to 31st Aug'18. I'm not sure what is the issue, what needs to be corrected. Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to loop through the items starting from the earliest date to the latest?  If so, you should use either `For i = 1 To myRestrictItems.Count` or `For Each myItem In myRestrictItems`.

Comment: Thanks. Let me rephrase my query again. I have created a folder in outlook where I keep all the mails coming in that specific month (Eg. Sep18). I receive mail on daily basic, so I'll have a mail of 1st sep, 2nd sep..till 30th Sep. Now, I want macro to go into the folder open 1st Sep'18 mail copy first table of the mail body into first worksheet of the excel, then go to 2nd sep and copy first table of 2nd sep mail to 2nd worksheet of excel and so on till 30 sep. The current macro is running randomly. Sometimes it moves from 4Sep to 6Sep and then goes to 5sep. I'm not sure how to resolve it

Comment: Use the Sort method of the Items object to sort your items before you loop through them -- `myRestrictItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"`.

Comment: Thanks Domenic. What will be the variable type for myRestrictitems .

Comment: myRestrictItems refers to an Items collection, as per this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict).

Comment: Thank Domenic for all your help and sorry that i'm still struggling with it. I tried to set the variable as Outlok.items, items, Object etc. but still getting an error. Not sure what I'm missing and what needs to be done.